# Charts for a real vector bundle

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-bundles

We know a vector  bundle as a manifold $E$ over a  manifold $M$ is defined using transition maps over a collection of open sets each giving  us a trivialization. Since $M$ is a manifold, it has an atlas. Can we intersect the two collections of open sets and obtain a chart for $E$ which also gives us the trivialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep!  Given an open set $U$ such that $E$ is trivial over $U$ and an open set $V$ that is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $U\cap V$ is an open set which is both diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on which $E$ is trivial.  Letting $U$ and $V$ range over open covers of $M$, you get an open cover of $M$ by sets of this form.  So you can always find an atlas for $M$ such that $E$ is trivial on each set in the atlas.